# How can pod make http request to other service in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I have built two services in k8s cluster, how can they interact with each other, if I want to make http request from one service to another, I know I can’t use local host, but how can I know the host when I am coding.

Comment: You can just call it like `http://<service>:port`

But make sure u expose it to the cluster
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Answer (score 3):

Service objects are automatically exposed in DNS as `<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.<clusterdomain>` where `clusterdomain` is usually `cluster.local`. The default resolv.conf allows for relative lookups so if the service is in the same namespace you can use just the name, otherwise `<servicename>.<namespace>`.